# React Native error on a line that doesn't exist

Tags: react-native, gradle, compiler-errors

I'm getting an error with the command trying to create my APK file so I can publish to the play store.

I'm running this command

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

The error I'm getting is

```
* Where:
Build file '/Users/frankinstyyn/Web Dev/Dyscalculator/react-native- 
calculator/MyProject/android/app/build.gradle' line: 225

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file '/Users/frankinstyyn/Web Dev/Dyscalculator/react-native- 
calculator/MyProject/android/app/build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
build file '/Users/frankinstyyn/Web Dev/Dyscalculator/react-native- 
calculator/MyProject/android/app/build.gradle': 225: Unexpected character: '"' @ line 
225, column 43.
           ord System.console().readLine("\Alias pa
                               ^
```

The main issue I have is that line doesn't exist in my file - I only have 25 lines.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks